# In Swift, How to understand the "inline closure"?

Tags: swift3, closures

everyone. When I read the [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html), there is not a definition for inline closures.

Q1: How to understand inline in "inline closure"?
Q2: What is the different between "inline closure" and normal closure?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An inline value is a value that's used directly, without first being assigned to an intermediate variable. Consider these two examples:

```
let number = 1
print(number)
```

Here, `1` is assigned to an intermediate variable, `number`, which is then printed.

```
print(1)
```

Here, `1`, is an inlined integer literal, which is printed directly.

The same applies to closures.

```
let evenNumberFilter: (Int) -> Bool = { $0 % 2 == 0 }
print((0...10).filter(evenNumberFilter))
```

Here, `{ $0 % 2 == 0 }` is a closure (of type `(Int) -> Bool`) that's assigned to the intermediate variable `evenNumberFilter` before being used.

```
print((0...10).filter{ $0 % 2 == 0 })
```

In this case, `{ $0 % 2 == 0 }` was used directly. It's an inline closure.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander

Comment: Thanks @Alexander